# We are switching to Window 7 using citrix and w/in Citrix trying to use the "Run As A Different User" credentials

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, internet, citrix

Where is the admin switches to  "Run As A Different User" ..   NOT "Run As Administrator" with the IE executable ?

Comment: In Windows 7, I don't believe this is a feature anymore, unlike Windows XP. I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with a Shift+Right Click. This is in windows 7 Enterprise Edition. I haven't checked it on any other versions. It should be standard though.

Comment: I can confirm this exists in Windows 7 Business ( i.e. equal to the Windows XP Pro and Vista Business edition )

Comment: This is the answer.  Confirmed on Windows 7 Enterprise.